# Have to Replace a text which is in first row second column using linux

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I have a file which having content like below.i want to replace text which is in first row second column from text which is stored in variable called `var` please help me out.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$2;next}
     {$1=a[FNR]}1' CT-ColorMaster_3.0.0--ir48-48_build-48.mf var
```

Content of `file.mf`

```
SHA1(CT-ColorMaster_3.0.0--ir48-48_build-48.ovf)= **65769231a386fad1d7ed210422216a52ae6e00e1**
SHA1(CT-ColorMaster_3.0.0--ir48-48_build-48-disk1.vmdk)= b0de466259d30bd973f603adba746814b97e8946
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please add 3 simple things: 1- Sample Input(s) in CODE TAGS. 2- Sample expected output with all conditions of yours in CODE TAGS. 3- What you have tried?

Comment: Hi, your question sounds intriguing, however I am not really sure what you would like to achieve. Could you please elaborate a bit. What is the `awk` line trying to do. And what would like to replace where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## sed

```
var=foobar; sed -r "1s/^([^ ]+) [^ ]+/\1 $var/" file.mf
SHA1(CT-ColorMaster_3.0.0--ir48-48_build-48.ovf)= foobar
SHA1(CT-ColorMaster_3.0.0--ir48-48_build-48-disk1.vmdk)= b0de466259d30bd973f603adba746814b97e8946
```

The **sed -r** uses extended regular expressions, which is needed, to make the + work.

1s means to operate only on line 1, s = substitute.

'[^ ]+ ' is a common pattern, to search not greedy for a blank. As many non-blank-characters as you like, followed by a blank. Replace the following with $var.

With -i, you can change a file in place:

```
var=foobar
sed -i.bak -r "1s/^([^ ]+) [^ ]+/\1 $var/" file.mf
```

generates a backup file.mf.bak from file.mf, and writes the changes to file.mf .

Without backup:

```
var=foobar
sed -i -r "1s/^([^ ]+) [^ ]+/\1 $var/" file.mf
```

If your sed lacks the -i-option, use

```
sed -r "1s/^([^ ]+) [^ ]+/\1 $var/" file.mf > file.mf.new 
mv file.mf file.mf.bak
mv file.mf.new file.mf
```

Comment: If it is allways hexadecimal, but still preceeded with one single blank, YAGNI. If it is hexadecimal, but ergonomically always in lowercase for the letters, why would you add A-F? If the format changes, you have to control the input, that's live. You can check for a length of 40 chars too. Can it be followed by a remark? The information should be enough, to solve the problem more specifically, if needed.

Comment: I actually had to lookup YAGNI. But you are correct.

Comment: Command worked, changes reflecting only on console my need it has to change inside the file can you please help

Comment: @keshav: Added hints to -i.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you try to achieve?

```
var="this is some text"
awk -v var=$var `(NR==1){$2=var}1` file.mf
```

This outputs:

```
SHA1(CT-ColorMaster_3.0.0--ir48-48_build-48.ovf)= this is some text 
SHA1(CT-ColorMaster_3.0.0--ir48-48_build-48-disk1.vmdk)= b0de466259d30bd973f603adba746814b97e894
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your attempt is that the `var` is not a file. You can use a trick avoiding temporary files with <(echo "${var}"):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$2;next}
     {$1=a[FNR]}1' CT-ColorMaster_3.0.0--ir48-48_build-48.mf <(echo "${var}")
```

When the variable `var` is one line, your solution can be simplified into the solution of @kvantour.